# Breakpoints not being hit or methods not being called when using $http.get to call methods in APIController

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

When I call $http.get('/api/calendarevent/getall') in my Angular code, the breakpoints for the method in my API Controller that matches that route are not being hit.  I don't know if that means the methods in the controller aren't being called or if it's bypassing the breakpoints set in the method.  In the IE Developer tools, I receive a 500 error code.  So the method is being found but I'm not sure if it's being executed since I would have received some kind of 400 error if it wasn't being found.  Below, I've included the necessary code, can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Angular Code:

```
function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/calendarevent/getall').success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });

}
```

APIController:

```
public class CalendarEventController : ApiController
{

[HttpGet]

[ActionName("all")]

public object GetAll()
{

using (var entity = new RPOEntities())

{ 

CalendarEventViewModel returnModel = new CalendarEventViewModel();

var events = entity.CalendarEvents.Where(e => !e.Deleted);

var eventList = events.ToList();

var calendarEvents = eventList.Select(e => new

{

id = e.CalendarEventId,

title = e.Title,

start = e.StartDate,

end = e.EndDate,

url = "details/" + e.CalendarEventId.ToString(),

contact = e.Contact,

location = e.Location,

property     = e.AllProperties ? "All Properties" : e.Property != null ? 
e.Property.PropertyName : "",

active = e.Active,

canEdit = Helper.IsRPOAdmin || Helper.IsCorporateAdmin || (e.PropertyStaffId.HasValue && e.PropertyStaffId.Value == Helper.CurrentUserId)
}).ToList();

return new {
events = calendarEvents, 
color = "", 
textColor = "" };

}
        }
```

Comment: So you're asking whether your breakpoints are being skipped or your methods are not being called, then you say your methods aren't being called.  You should read the [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and edit your question *heavily* to make it useful.

Comment: No, I didn't say the method wasn't being called.  I said the breakpoints for my method aren't being hit.

Comment: Right, I misread.  Apologies.

Comment: you should try this url "/api/calendarevent/all" not this "/api/calendarevent/getall" beacuse you are giving actioname as "all" in your action method. 
[ActionName("all")]
public object GetAll()